# How to convert Ai file to SVG while keeping the layer name the same?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have an ai file that I want to convert to svg file for websites. It is quite a large file with lots of object, I want to keep the objects name the same as the ai file in svg file. But when I convert, the name of the objects changes. How can I convert to svg while keeping the objects/layers name the same?

1st image is the ss from ai. 2nd one is from svg

[image: File names in ai]

[image: File names in svg]